# Python: DataFrame Index shifting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes that I have concatenated with pandas in the line:

```
 xspc = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis = 1, join_axes = [df3.index])
```

In df2 the index values read one day later than the values of df1, and df3.  So for instance when the most current date is 7/1/19 the index values for df1 and df3 will read "7/1/19" while df2 reads '7/2/19'.  I would like to be able to concatenate each series so that each dataframe is joined on the most recent date, so in other words I would like all the dataframe values from df1 index value '7/1/19' to be concatenated with dataframe 2 index value '7/2/19' and dataframe 3 index value '7/1/19'.  When methods can I use to shift the data around to join on these not matching index values?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.  For instance, do the date all line up?  Such that the first item in df2 should always be aligned to the first item in df1 or is it possible that df2[0] is a closer match to df1[2].

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the index of the data frame and then concat the dataframes

```
df1=df1.reset_index()
df2=df2.reset_index()
df3=df3.reset_index()

df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1, join_axes=[df3.index])
```

This should work since you  mentioned that the date in df2 will be one day after df1 or df3

Comment: Shouldn't that be `reset_index`, not `rest_index`?

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  The OP asked to match on dates not to match on a new index.

Comment: Thanks DM, with an edit it appears that at the index value of zero the most recent dates are all included. The main difference being the date value for the second dataframe is a day later than the other dataframe date values.